# Running testng webdriver test using Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, remote-desktop

I wrote some tests (webriver, testng), but since running them takes kinda much time and i can't use  my PC when webdriver is working. Now i'm trying to run them on different machine using Remote Desktop Connection. I copied my tests to the other machine, compiled them and try to run, but webdriver can't find any element of tested page (even by tagName "body"). Is it possible to do it the way i'm trying? Or i have to use grid for that?
i'm using selenium server standalone 2.33
(sorry for my english and lacks of knowlage but i'm student new to the webdriver stuff :) )

Comment: I would update Selenium first. What browser? What version of that browser? Also show us the code used to initialise the driver for your test. Can you replicate the same issue using a new project, pointing at somewhere else? Such as just navigating to StackOverflow?

Comment: browser IE7. I made new project on remote machine and there i tried to navigate to stack overflow and click element and it worked, so now i got answer to my question if is it even possible (got something wrong there but now i know the direction) Thank you very much :)

Comment: your question is very confusing.. are you wanting to treat your RDP point as a node? orrr...

Comment: @sircapsalot Sorry, its hard for me to ask this kind of questions in english. Simply what i wanted to do:
1. Write test on my PC
2. Send test to a remote machine
3. Run test on remote machine using remote dekstop connection
4. Write another test on my PC while test is running on remote machine

Comment: Gotcha - ok.. i'll write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want, is a Selenium Grid.

There are at least 2 separate entities that you need.  You need...

1. `A Grid server`
2. `A Node`

In your case, what you will do, is for your RDP machine that you have access to, you'll want to run your `selenium-server-standalone.jar` with the `-role node -hub http://my.hub.ip` arguments attached.

For the hub (should be either your computer, or another dedicated server) is run the `selenium-server-standalone.jar` with the `-role hub` arguments attached.

Then what you'll do, is when you are on YOUR computer, write your test, you can fire tests at the grid, which will fire the tests, in turn, at any available node. In your case, your RDP.